# Accessing data from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model which has a scope that returns all potentially eligible customers for an automated emailing list; however, there are further checks that are required.

To get the fields needed for the email, I do the following (snippet):

```
Customers.eligible.each do |customer|
  name: customer.order.first_name
  email: customer.order.contact_info.email
end
```

I was wonder if there is a nicer way to do this? I'd usually extract the logic into it's own method, e.g.

```
def first_name
  customer.order.first_name
end
```

However, as I have to iterate over each eligible active record, I am unable to do this.

Any ideas? All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: would be easier if `contact_info` has the `first_name` as well, in that case you can make a query joining `order` and `customer` and selecting the 2 fields you need... something like `ContactInfo.select('email, first_name').joins(order: :customer).where(customer eligibility where here)`

Comment: You could use delegation as well e.g. `class Order; delegate :email to: :contact_info` then `customer.order.email` would work as well that being said a bit more context might make this question easier to answer from an efficiency standpoint (as I fear it is probably highly inefficient right now due to iterative associative queries) [More on delegation](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience you should be able to able to use the first_name instance method. For the below class method you can definitely evoke the first_name instance method per each customer object.

```
Customers.eligible.each do |customer|
 name: customer.first_name
 email: customer.order.contact_info.email
end

def first_name
 self.order.first_name
end
```

Just make sure not to use the instance methods with customer instance which are not eligible for the mail list.